# create entities for a dynamically created database in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, smo

I have an application where I create database's dynamically in a SQL Server using Server Management Objects through my application.

I want to use the Entity Framework to access this database when it has been created, is this possible?  As I can not generate Entity classes from a database in VS. I do have the structure of the database of course.

So is it possible to create the Entity classes manually and is that a do-able task?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's completely possible. You can even manipulate the generated code if you want.

What you might want to take a look is the EDMX XML specification.

In that file you specify the underlying database, views, functions, procedures and the like, as well as the desired objects. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982042.aspx) in order to have more information.

Answer (score 1):

Paulo is right for EF 1 (+1). For EF 4, I'd suggest using [code-only modeling](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/06/10/code-only.aspx) instead.